# World Health Organisation (WHO)... or Organization?

Tags: american-english, british-english

In an article for the U.S., do you keep the s- or change it to a z-? The organization's official name is, of course, with an s-.
The same reversed: would the World Hemophilia federation become the World Haemophilia Federation if speaking about it in UK?

Comment: In general, if the organization spells its name the same way in all documents, regardless of where the document is intended for, I follow the organization's lead, and use a consistent spelling. If the organization translates or respells its name for other areas, I do so as well (i.e., I continue to follow the organization's lead). If I am working for an organization that has a 'house style guide' (e.g., a newspaper), I follow the house style if it specifies, and the original organization's lead where the house style doesn't specify.

Comment: http://www.who.int/

Comment: *The organization's official name is, of course, with an s-.* It is?

Answer (score 4):

The main practical reason to use consistent orthography is to aid the reader; switching spelling, spacing, punctuation, and so forth is distracting and introduces ambiguity.

In line with using forms familiar to the reader, common practice historically was to localize spellings. Consider, for example, contemporary reporting on the September 11, 2001 terrorist attacks in the U.S.; British broadsheets referred consistently to the World Trade *Centre*, rather than the World Trade *Center* as it was and is spelled by its owners, tenants, and neighbors in New York.

> Both towers of the World Trade Centre in New York and part of the Pentagon building in Washington DC have collapsed after hijacked aircraft crashed into them. ([*The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2001/sep/11/september11.usa))
>
> Two hijacked passenger airliners crashed into the twin towers of New York's World Trade Centre. ([*The Daily Telegraph*](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/northamerica/usa/1340318/America-on-war-footing.html))

The alternative approach is to use the orthography used or preferred by the person or entity itself. *The Guardian* [switched to this standard](https://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2014/nov/21/mind-your-language-center-or-centre) (local spelling) a few years ago in the interest of accuracy and serving an international audience, noting also that their use of *World Trade Centre* but *Pearl Harbor* was inconsistent.

I don't find this approach obviously better; for example, I find the flipping back and forth depending on whether you are talking about a *centre* or the *Center* distracting in this example [from the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-oxfordshire-44531917):

> **Oxford University Mohammed bin Rashid centre 'doesn't exist'**
> The Dubai government published a press release with a photo about the opening of the 'Mohammed bin Rashid Center for Future Research' at Oxford University.…
> "We can confirm that there is no centre with this name at Oxford University," a university spokesman said.

Ultimately, as with transliteration and disputed names, such matters are a question of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application. It is in fact common for a particular publication or organization to follow one standard overall, but [make various exceptions](https://www.nice.org.uk/corporate/ecd1/chapter/spelling-and-choosing-the-right-word).

If you do adopt the standard of using the entity's preferred or most common spelling, consider that their internal [style guide](http://www.unaids.org/sites/default/files/sg13_web_v4%20pdf%20-%20adobe%20reader.pdf) specifies

> World Health Organization, WHO, the Organization (not World Health Organisation, the WHO)

Indeed, even the logo on [who.int](http://www.who.int/) indicates [Oxford spelling](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/28/ize-or-ise/):

[image: WHO logo showing the name of the organization as World Health Organization]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Spellings get changed as per the country in which a particular word is being used ESPECIALLY when it's an organisation. I would always prefer to use the name registered in the country of it's origin.
However,if generally talking about Hemophilia, such alteration is acceptable.